# How can I refresh the Id Token in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, spring-authorization-server

I created a CustomTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory and it works fine. But I also want to refresh the Id token, does anyone have an idea how I can go about that?

```
private Mono<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> refreshAuthorizedClient(
            final ServerWebExchange exchange,
            final OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient,
            final OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Authentication) {
        final ClientRegistration clientRegistration = authorizedClient.getClientRegistration();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth(clientRegistration.getClientId(), clientRegistration.getClientSecret());
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        return webClientBuilder.build()
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .uri(clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getTokenUri())
                .headers(header -> header.addAll(headers))
                .bodyValue(refreshTokenBody(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue()))
                .exchangeToMono(refreshResponse -> {
                    if (refreshResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)) {
                        System.err.println("The refresh token or sessions expired.");
                        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, TOKEN_REFRESHMENT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else {
                        return refreshResponse.body(oauth2AccessTokenResponse());
                    }
                })
                .map(accessTokenResponse -> {
                    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = Optional.ofNullable(accessTokenResponse.getRefreshToken())
                            .orElse(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken());
                    System.err.println(accessTokenResponse.getAdditionalParameters());
                    return new OAuth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient.getClientRegistration(), authorizedClient.getPrincipalName(), accessTokenResponse.getAccessToken(), refreshToken);
                })
                .flatMap(result -> this.authorizedClientRepository.saveAuthorizedClient(result, oauth2Authentication, exchange).thenReturn(result));
    }

    private static MultiValueMap<String, String> refreshTokenBody(final String refreshToken) {
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add(GRANT_TYPE_KEY, AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN.getValue());
        body.add(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY, refreshToken);
        return body;
    }
```

Comment: "But I also want to refresh the Id token" Can you point to a specification or give some context around why you would want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? An `id_token` is not the same as an `access_token`, so you should provide context around why you're doing this so others finding this question are misled to think it's a standard thing to do.

Comment: I just want to get a better understanding of how Spring Security works with Spring Authorization Server. The intention is not to create an actual project.

Comment: I see. Well, because `id_token` is not intended to be refreshed per the OpenID Connect specification (AFAIK), it's not something that you can really do in an intentional way.

Comment: If the id token cannot be refreshed it does mean that you cannot log out after 30 minutes. Or am I seeing that wrong?

Comment: From [OpenID Connect RP-Initiated Logout 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RPLogout), "The OP SHOULD accept ID Tokens when the RP identified by the ID Token's aud claim and/or sid claim has a current session or had a recent session at the OP, even when the exp time has passed." The provider should accept recent but expired id_tokens. The meaning of "recent" is left up to the provider. Nothing in the spec (from my reading) indicates that a refresh mechanism for ID Tokens is required.

Comment: Additionally, if you think about it, the id_token expiration and the session length of the provider could (should?) match, so refreshing the id_token makes no sense. If the token expires, so does the session and there's no need to log out. The logout flow (if initiated from the client) should succeed without doing anything.

Comment: After a few tests, I noticed that in the OidcLogoutAuthenticationProvider class, the id token is rejected in the authenticate method.

OAuth2Authorization.Token<OidcIdToken> authorizedIdToken = authorization.getToken(OidcIdToken.class);
  if (!authorizedIdToken.isActive()) {
   throwError(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_TOKEN, "id_token_hint");
  }
Returns an error message if the Id token has expired.
Is it a good idea to rewrite the OidcLogoutAuthenticationProvider class and omit the test "isActive"?

Comment: "Is it a good idea..." I'm not sure I can answer that. But you shouldn't have to. This might be a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1440